# How do I end this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning node.js and express js. I am following a tutorial but mine is generating this error.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Though the code works as wanted but I get this error on the console.log. The code is for user authentication for username and password.

Here is the exact code generating this error: This error only happens when I tried to test wrong password or username.

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) =>{
try {
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");

    const passValidate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    !passValidate && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");

    const {password, ...others} = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others)
} catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
   
}

});
```

Comment: you set `res.status(...)` thrice inside `try`

Comment: @depperm How best can I write the codes? They all test username, password and the last one is when both username, password match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `res.status(...)` three times in your try. Reducing this down to one time will get rid of this error.

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
        let passValidate
        if(user) {
            passValidate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
        }

        if(!user || !passValidate) {
            res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
        } else {
            const {password, ...others} = user._doc;
            res.status(200).json(others)
        }
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. This code solved the problem but the username is no longer returning 'wrong credential' when it is wrong.

Comment: @Kingsley what is the return?

Comment: It is giving back empty object in Postman. Not generating the "Wrong credential" Password worked fine.

Comment: does adding `.exec()` to the end of the `const user...` line fix it?

Comment: It didn't fix it.

Comment: if you add `console.log(user)` after `const user..` line with bad user, what is the output

Comment: I got null on the console.log(user) when the user's name is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236362/discussion-between-depperm-and-kingsley).

Comment: Your latest update to the code solved my problem. Thank you. I only had to use 'let' to declare the passValidate variable instead of  'const' and that solved the problem. Thank you once again.